# Javascript doesn't sort list items properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, columnsorting

I have - array of objects - list items, I sort these items by `fieldName`. Normally it seems it works fine, but on some items it behaves strange and doesn't sort items properly.

Here is the code that I am making sorting:

```
elements.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[fieldName] === '' || a[fieldName] == null) return 1;
      if (b[fieldName] === '' || b[fieldName] == null) return -1;

      return (
        itemSort
          ? a[fieldName]?.toLowerCase() < b[fieldName]?.toLowerCase()
          : a[fieldName]?.toLowerCase() > b[fieldName]?.toLowerCase()
      )
        ? 1
        : -1;
    })
```

`itemSort` is a boolean and I decide to make `A-Z` or `Z-A` sorting.

Here is a picture from strange behaviour, I only see the wrong sorting on these items.
[image]

Here is an example of `elements`

```
[
{
icon: "IssueTracking"
id: "62a0868c2b2b180061ab05d8"
name: "[DEMO ASLC] All Issues"
type: "sheet"
updatedAt: "2022-12-05T15:17:23.072Z"
url: "/admin/documents/edit/62a0868c2b2b180061ab05d8"
},
{
icon: "..."
id: "..."
name: "..."
type: "..."
updatedAt: "..."
url: "..."
},
...
]
```

Comment: use localeCompare instead

Comment: Can you share `elements` array as well?

Comment: @SedatPolat I shared a sample of `elements`

Comment: There is `name` not `fieldName` in the object.

Comment: `fieldName` is dynamic, so it can be `name`, `type`, `id` and etc.

Comment: but of course if you have `const fieldName = 'name'`, it should be ok. You should post your question with min reproducable example. Otherwise answer will not be %100 helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sort()` method modifies array itself, so you need to copy the array into a new array if you would like to keep your original array order in place.

```js
const elementArray = [
  { name: "abc" },
  { name: "abb" },
  { name: "cc" },
  { name: "1bb" },
  { name: "4bc" },
  { name: "abb4" },
  { name: "" },
];

const sortItems = (elements, asc = true) => {
  const sortedArray = [...elements];
  sortedArray.sort((a, b) => {

    let sortResult = a.name?.toLowerCase() > b.name?.toLowerCase() ?  1 : -1;
      
      return asc ? sortResult : sortResult * -1
  
  });
  return sortedArray;
};

console.log(`descending: ${JSON.stringify(sortItems(elementArray, false))}`);
console.log(`ascending: ${JSON.stringify(sortItems(elementArray))}`);
```

Answer (score -2):

One of the best way to do this is to use the [Lodash sortBy method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy).
You can install this library with npm or yarn and simply do `_.sortBy(elements, 'fieldName')`

Comment: Inplementing a complete libary for one function is a bit overkill if you ask me. Especially since you should be able to this in plain js just fine.